# Magento 2.3 - How to send associative as a response using custom rest API?

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

I need to send associative array in response. Keys can be dynamic like

```
{
 'a':'1',
 'b':'2'
}
```

I already tried `mixed[], mixed, string, string[], array and array[]`. But I always get following result.

```
{
 '1',
 '2'
}
```

Comment: string[]
Have you try this?

Comment: @BirjitsinhZala - Yes I tried, it didn't worked.

Comment: hiii, have you checked my updated answere?

Comment: Hi, yes. First option is not working. Second option is working but it is adding escape character '\' in the response like "[{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\"}]". Seems I will need to handle it client side.

Comment: I mean to say create new file interface AssociativeArrayItemInterface

Comment: '\' it's looks like double time converted to json

Comment: did you try wrapping your output with square brackets like this `return [$output];`. I guess the `$output` itself is an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

First create this interface in your app/code/Vendor/Module/Api/Data

```
/**
 * Interface which represents associative array item.
 */
interface AssociativeArrayItemInterface
{
    /**
     * Get key
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey();

    /**
     * Get value
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue();
}
```

Apply @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\AssociativeArrayItemInterface[] datatype for on comment

```
/**
    * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\AssociativeArrayItemInterface[]
    **/
    public function getSettings();

    /**
    * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\AssociativeArrayItemInterface[]
    **/
    public function getExtra();
```

SECOND OPTION: send data in below formate

```
[{"a":"1","b":"2"}]
```

Comment: Or second  option send in array: [{"a":"1","b":"2"}]

Comment: Your second option cannot work as the `{}` symbols can't be used.